# Outlook: Accessing other e-mail addresses from left-hand panel

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

At work, we have a couple of shared/common e-mail addresses, for example "hr@company.com" and "hseq@company.com". I have access to a couple of these folders/email-addresses, but in order to do it, I have to go file->open and export->Another user's folder->type in name. I'm using Outlook 2013.

The question I have is: How do I get the email folder/account, e.g. "hr@company.com", visible on the left hand side in Outlook? Right now I only have firstname.lastname@company.com visible. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi - Assuming your own personal email account and the common ones are based on the same domain, you can add the hr@... and hseq@... account to the default account, by:

1. Open Outlook 2013 and Click File.

2. Click Info, Account Settings, Account Settings…

3. Highlight your current email account and click Change

4. Server settings box should appear, click More Settings.

5. Click the Advanced Tab and Click Add

6. Type in the name of the additional/second mailbox (f.ex. hr@company.com & hseq@company.com) you want to add and click OK.

The shared process mailboxes will now appear in the left hand panel.